# Defining constant in two pages and including one in the other

Tags: php

What will happen if a constant is defined on one page say index.php and then again defined on the other page say header.php and then header.php is included in index.php? This question was asked in an interview and I am wondering what the outcome would really be.

Comment: The variable is the same because it's considered from the same script. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483759/how-to-use-php-variables-from-an-included-php-file

Comment: My question is about constants and not variables @MathieuDormeval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have used `error_reporting(E_ALL);` It will show you

`Notice: Constant 'CONSTANT NAME' already defined in 'file name'`.

Better you check before define new constant like:

```
if (!defined(CONSTANT)) { define ('CONSTANT', 'Constant Value'); }
```

Comment: Thanks @Ram  :) Ram ji ki chaal dekho ;)